# SQL union of time series tables, ignoring/removing duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I'm looking for some help with a PostgreSQL query.
I have subqueries from 2 tables and both have all columns in common, but the data in both may differ:

tab1 (may sometimes be empty, because of conditional statement that is not met in the subquery)

```
+---------+------------+
|   ts    | value      |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1002       |
| 2       | 3234       |
| 3       | 530        |
| 4       | 340        |
+---------+------------+
```

tab2 (always has data)

```
+---------+------------+
|   ts    | value      |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1303       |
| 2       | 9000       |
| 3       | 4003       |
| 4       | 924        |
| 5       | 225        |
| 6       | 346        |
+---------+------------+
```

I need to extend tab1 with tab2 values. So I concatenate them and discard duplicate rows if ts (time steps) are the same in both. I came up with this:

WITH my_select AS
(SELECT ts, value,
FROM tab1)
SELECT * FROM my_select
UNION ALL
SELECT ts, value
FROM tab2 WHERE AND ts > (SELECT max(ts) FROM my_select)

```
+---------+------------+
|   ts    | value      |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1002       |
| 2       | 3234       |
| 3       | 530        |
| 4       | 340        |
| 5       | 225        |
| 6       | 346        |
+---------+------------+
```

This concatenation obviously only works when the first table has data, otherwise max(ts) fails and no data appears. Ideally, in this case, I would like just tab2 data to be returned if no tab1 data is available.
Is there a more elegant solution you can suggest, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select ts, value
from tab1
union all
select t1, value
from tab2
where not exists (select 1 from tab1 where tab1.ts = tab2.ts);
```